# PostgreSql Trigger does not work when called 'insert'

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

The code below is my code to create trigger function to change column "pass".

```
create or replace function change_pass()
returns trigger as
$$
begin
 NEW.pass := 'XXXXXXXXX';
 return NEW;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger change_pass
AFTER insert or update on "D_ACCOUNT"
for each row execute procedure change_pass();
```

When i called insert, i did not see any changes in my data. 
Can anyone explain to me where i was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BEFORE` trigger to change values in the `NEW` record:

```
create trigger change_pass
  BEFORE insert or update on "D_ACCOUNT"
for each row execute procedure change_pass();
```